# Model Binding editable table fields within a form (Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, html-table, razor-pages

My Asp.Net 6 - Razor Pages application has an editable table within a form.

I am trying to bind the editable table fields to a model but am not sure how to do so because `td` fields cannot be used with `asp-for` tag helpers.

I want to be able to retrieve the edited values from the table in the Page Model's `OnPost()` method.

These are the ids of the two editable table columns that I want to retrieve the values from:

- For `id="importColumn"`, when a user clicks on a cell, the cell value for this column gets changed from a tick to a cross using a Javascript on-click handler.
- For `id="modifiedColumnNames"`, the user modifies the value of any cell within this column.

**.cshtml Form:**

```
<form method="post" asp-antiforgery="true">
   <table id="columnsToImportTable" class="display roundedCorners" width="100%">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th class="centreText">Column Name</th>
            <th class="centreText">Import Column</th>
            <th class="centreText">Database Column Name</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         @for (var i = 0; i < Model.newLayer.ColumnNames.Count(); i++)
         {
         <tr>
            <td class="greyOutBackground centreText defaultCursor">@Model.newLayer.ColumnNames[i]</td>
            <td id="importColumn" class="greyOutBackground centreText pointerCursor green tick true">&#10004;
               <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.newLayer.ImportColumn[i]" value="true">
            </td>
            <td id="modifiedColumnNames">
               <div contenteditable>@Model.newLayer.ColumnNames[i]</div>
               <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.newLayer.ColumnNames[i]">
            </td>
         </tr>
         }
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div>
      <input id="importButton" type="submit" value="Import">
   </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript/Jquery click handler:**

```
$('#columnsToImportTable td.tick').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('true')) {
        $this.html('<td id="importColumn" class="greyOutBackground centreText pointerCursor red tick false centreElement">&#10006;<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.newLayer.ImportColumn[i]" value="false"></td>');
    } else {
        $this.html('<td id="importColumn" class="greyOutBackground centreText pointerCursor green tick true centreElement">&#10004;<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.newLayer.ImportColumn[i]" value="true"></td>');
    }

    $this.toggleClass('true');
});
```

**The Model:**

```
public class NewLayer
    {
        public List<string> ColumnNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public List<string> ColumnDataTypes { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public List<string> LayerNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public List<string> ImportColumn { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public string SelectedLayer { get; set; } = null!;
        public string SelectedNameField { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

**The Page Model:**

```
public class IndexModel: PageModel {
  private FileProcessor _FileProcessor = new FileProcessor();
  private AppContext _context;

  [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
  public NewLayer newLayer {get;set;}

  public IndexModel(AppContext context) {
    _context = context;
    newLayer = new NewLayer();
  }

  public void OnGet() {
    var filePath = "[FilePath]";

      var ColumnNamesAndDatatypes = _FileProcessor.GetColumnNamesAndTypes(filePath);

      for (var i = 0; i < ColumnNamesAndDatatypes.Count(); i++) {
        newLayer.ColumnNames.Add(ColumnNamesAndDatatypes[i].ColumnName);
        newLayer.ColumnDataTypes.Add(ColumnNamesAndDatatypes[i].DataType);
        newLayer.ImportColumn.Add("true");
      }

      newLayer.LayerNames = _context.Layers.Select(l => l.LayerName).ToList();
  }

  public void OnPost(NewLayer newLayer) {
    var test = this.newLayer;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the Model Binding method to submit the form and transfer the data from the client to the back-end, we should set the hidden field's name property based on the view model and the index.

To the `importColumn` column, when user click on the cell, you could use `clone()` method to get the `importColumn` hidden field, then change its value attribute, and finally add it to the new `td` element.

To the `modifiedColumnNames` column, when user modifies the value, you need to copy the contenteditable div content to the hidden field. you can use the div's `input` event.

You can refer to the following code:

Html elements: add class for the modifiedColumnNames hidden field.

```
<form method="post" asp-antiforgery="true">
   <table id="columnsToImportTable" class="display roundedCorners" width="100%">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th class="centreText">Column Name</th>
            <th class="centreText">Import Column</th>
            <th class="centreText">Database Column Name</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         @for (var i = 0; i < Model.newLayer.ColumnNames.Count(); i++)
         {
         <tr>
            <td class="greyOutBackground centreText defaultCursor">@Model.newLayer.ColumnNames[i]</td>
            <td id="importColumn" class="greyOutBackground centreText pointerCursor green tick true">&#10004;
               <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.newLayer.ImportColumn[i]" value="true">
            </td>
            <td id="modifiedColumnNames">
               <div class="editdiv" contenteditable>@Model.newLayer.ColumnNames[i]</div>
               <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.newLayer.ColumnNames[i]">
            </td>
         </tr>
         }
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div>
      <input id="importButton" type="submit" value="Import">
   </div>
</form>
```

JS code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#columnsToImportTable td.tick').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            // get the ImportColumn hidden field.
            var hiddentag = $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").clone();
            if ($this.hasClass('true')) {
                //change the hidend field' value 
                $(hiddentag).attr("value","false");
                //get the html 
                var newtag = $(hiddentag)[0].outerHTML;
                $this.html('<td id="importColumn" class="greyOutBackground centreText pointerCursor red tick false centreElement">&#10006;' + newtag + '</td>');
            } else {
                $(hiddentag).attr("value","true");
                var newtag = $(hiddentag)[0].outerHTML;
                $this.html('<td id="importColumn" class="greyOutBackground centreText pointerCursor green tick true centreElement">&#10004;' + newtag + '</td>');
            }
            $this.toggleClass('true');
        });
        //
        $(".editdiv").each(function(index, item){
            $(item).on('propertychange input', function (e) {
                $(this).next("input[type='hidden']").val($(this).text());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    //private FileProcessor _FileProcessor = new FileProcessor();
    //private AppContext _context;

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public NewLayer newLayer { get; set; }

    public IndexModel()
    { 
        newLayer = new NewLayer();
    }

    public void OnGet()
    { 
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            newLayer.ColumnNames.Add("Name " + i.ToString());
            newLayer.ColumnDataTypes.Add("DataType " + i.ToString());
            newLayer.ImportColumn.Add("true");
        }

        newLayer.LayerNames = new List<string>() { "L1", "L2" };
    }

    public void OnPost(NewLayer newLayer)
    {
        var test = this.newLayer;
    }
}
```

The result is like this:

[image]